# How can an orbital be recognised from the wavefunction notation?

Tags: wavefunction, atoms, notation, orbitals

I am a student and was working up the exercises in my book when I came across a problem that required me to identify the orbital given by $ \psi_{3,2,1}\,.$ What I can work out is that the sub-shell is 3d but I am having trouble working out the orbital. Can anyone help please?

I looked up on google but got nothing concrete. Please help.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'identify the orbital'. The orbital is completely characterised by the list of quantum numbers which you have; so what more do you want?

Comment: Your instructor probably means this to be a *very* easy question, just as lemon implies. The answer is written down in front of you to within converting the numeric value of $n$ to the proper letter (s,p,d,f,...).